# Is it possible to load a premade BIOS config onto a clean machine?

Tags: scripting, boot, bios

Basically, what I'm trying to do is wipe a machine and load a pre-configured BIOS onto it on boot, whether it be through a disk, CD or USB. I'm open to programming a script, but I've yet to figure out what tools or languages I could use to approach this problem.

Also, if there's already a similar post to this on SO, I would appreciate a link. I tried searching for it, but I may be using the wrong keywords to find the particular answer I'm looking for.

I looked into the Dell OpenManage DTK, but my conclusion was that it didn't do what I wanted it to, for it seems like it updates BIOS settings onto other machines from a centralized machine, which is not what I want since you'd have to have already set up a minimal BIOS config that includes enabled iDRAC on those machines already.

Much appreciated fellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some BIOS will allow you to load a configuration via USB drive or floppy disk, none that I am aware of will allow you to have a configuration load automatically on boot. This would actually be a huge security vulnerability so I doubt you'll be able to find a way to do this.

An alternate solution is that you could probably find many motherboards with removable BIOS chips and use an EEPROM burner to preload the BIOS chips with the configuration you want. Here is a listing of numerous EEPROM burners on this site: http://www.sivava.com/EPROM_Programmer_4.html

Comment: Well, if I can load a BIOS configuration from USB, couldn't I make that the permanent config? Basically, I'm trying to change the BIOS configuration without having to do it manually for every new machine we get, preferably through a script. If I can load a BIOS config from an external source, wouldn't I be able to change the machine's config to it too?

Thanks for the info btw :]

Comment: Yes, you could make it permanent. Many BIOS will allow you save a configuration to a disk, and load the configuration from a disk. It seems like you may want this to be a generic configuration, though. Are you wanting to load the same configuration on different types/brands/models of motherboards? Unfortunately, that probably won't be possible as each motherboard has a slightly different configuration and different configurable options. All machines would need to have identical boards.

Comment: Nope, the BIOS I would want to preload would always be on the same type of motherboard. I'd obviously make a new one if we had a new motherboard type introduced to the equation, but assuming all same motherboards, I'd want to create a BIOS configuration (so that I could bump up the NIC to be the bootable device, allowing me to copy the machine image from network) that I could load onto the machine from disk. This is to avoid having to manually do the boot order on the machines since I have to do it on dozens of them.

Comment: Without knowing the specific model of computer you're working with, it's difficult for me to assist you any further, but you ought to be able to go into the BIOS on one of the machines and see if there is an option to save and load the configuration the configuration to or from a disk. If you can do that, you should have no trouble loading the configuration on to the other computers that you're working with

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think to look to see if there was that kind of an option in the BIOS console... I guess I just assumed there wasn't since nobody else had done it. I'll look into it.

Comment: They're just Dell server blades, btw. I don't remember off the top of my head the type, I'm just trying to automate the BIOS config part of it so that our infrastructure dudes don't spend an hour every time we get new blades on manual junk.

Comment: Nah, there was no save or load config to/from disk option :/ Working on Dell PowerEdge blades.

Comment: I believe that your only option, then, would be the EEPROM burner that I was talking about in my original answer. You could burn an EEPROM for each server and install it, but I'm not sure that this would be much easier than just setting up the BIOS manually as it would involve opening each case, removing the old BIOS chip, and installing a new one.